# Optimising export of DB using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a RoR application which contains an API to manage applications, each of which contain recipes (and groups, ingredients, measurements).

Once the user has finished managing the recipes, they download a JSON file of the entire application. Because each application could have hundreds of recipes, the files can be large. It also means there is a lot of DB calls to get all the required data to export.

Now because of this, the request to download the application can take upwards of 30 seconds, sometimes more.

My current code looks something like this:

```
application.categories.each do |c|
  c.recipes.each do |r|
      r.groups.each do |r|
          r.ingredients.each do |r|
```

Within each loop I'm storing the data in a HASH and then giving it to the user.

My question is: where do I go from here?

- Is there a way to grab **all** the data I require from the DB in one query? From looking at the log, I can see it is running hundreds of queries.
- If the above solution is still slow, is this something I should put into a background process, and then email the user a link (or similar)?

Comment: `joins` Application.categories.joins(:recipies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course ways to grab more data at once. This is done with Rails `includes` or `joins`, depending on your needs. See [this article](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/) for some detailed information.

The basic idea is that you can join between your tables so that each time new queries aren't generated. When you do `application.categories`, that's one query. For each of those categories, you'll do another query: `c.recipes` - this creates N+1 queries, where N is the number of categories you have. Rather, you can include them off the get go to create 1 or 2 queries (depending on what Rails does).

The basic syntax is easy:

```
Application.includes(:categories => :recipes).each do |application| ...
```

This generates 1 (or 2 - again, see article) query that grabs all applications, their categories, and each categories recipies all at once. You can tack on the groups and ingredients too.

As for putting the work in the background, my suggestion would be to just have a loading image, or get fancy by using a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `#preload` after reading that article. My export call went from being 13s locally to being under 1s.

Comment: @rdougan That's an awesome improvement!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have to assume that the required `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations exist.

Generally you can do something like

```
c.recipes.includes(:groups)
```

or even

```
c.recipes.includes(:groups => :ingredients)
```

which will fetch recipes and groups (and ingredients) at once.

But since you have a quite big data set IMO it would be better if you limited that technique to  the deepest levels.

The most usefull approach would be to use [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) and `includes` together.

(`find_each` fetches the items in batches in order to keep the memory usage low)

perhaps something like

```
application.categories.each do |c|
  c.recipes.find_each do |r|
    r.groups.includes(:ingredients).each do |r|
      r.ingredients.each do |r|
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now even that can take quite a long time (for an http request) so you can consider using some async processing where the client will generate a request that is going to be processed by the server as a background job, and when that is ready, you can provide a download link (or send an email) to the client.

[Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) is one possible solution for handling the async part.